# WiX Burn Bootstrapper detected as virus/malware by trend micro

Tags: wix, registry, wix3.6, antivirus, bootstrapper

When installing certain packages in a WiX Burn bootstrapper, the installation gets cut off shortly after clicking install by Trend Micro OfficeScan. It detects it as potential virus/malware because it is trying to write to a registry location like: HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce{*GUID*}

The install uses a custom bootstrapper application built with WiX 3.6 and had previously been working for a few months at our office before it suddenly showed up as a virus. I checked with the head of IT and no changes have recently been made to the AV settings.

After a bit of searching I found that others have had this issue in the past but most over a year ago. At that time the general consensus was to inform the AV companies of the false positives, which I assume worked because of the lack of issues over the past year.
There were also some suggestions to ensure that the bootstrapper application and setup.exe were signed which I have also tried but to no effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I discovered the route of the problem when comparing the log files for packages that weren't detected as virus' by the AV with those that were. I discovered a difference when the bundle was being cached:

(Success)
Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users*user*\AppData\Local\Temp{GUID}.be\Setup.exe' to: 'C:\ProgramData\Package Cache{GUID}\Setup.exe'
Registering bundle dependency provider: {GUID}, version: 1.1.1.0

v

(Fail)
Caching bundle from: 'C:\Users*user*\AppData\Local\Temp{GUID}.be\Setup.exe' to: 'C:\Users*user*\AppData\Local\Package Cache{GUID}\Setup.exe'
Registering bundle dependency provider: {GUID}, version: 1.1.1.0

The reason for the difference is that the top MSI is a per machine installation whereas the bottom was per user.

In our specific case the MSI's shouldn't have been installed per user anyway but per machine and so changing them to be per machine installations fixed our issue.

Hopefully this might avoid others getting stuck in a similar situation but if anyone else has an answer that solves the "Per user" installation issue please share because that could become an issue at a later date.